# How can I display a property value infront of each JSON array item?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Here is the JSON string that I am working with.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "A Test",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 157,
      "title": "some article",      
      "type": "Article"
    },
    {
      "id": 153,
      "title": "some other article",     
      "type": "Article"
    }
   ]
}
```

I am using Json.Net for serialization. Is there anyway that I can format the JSON like this before displaying?

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "A Test",
  "items": [
    "157" : {
      "title": "some article",      
      "type": "Article"
    },
    "153" : {
      "title": "some other article",     
      "type": "Article"
    }
   ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language are you talking about? There's obviously no default way to do so, as such format is not a real JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get pretty close to the output you want using Json.Net's LINQ-to-JSON API (JObjects) to transform the original JSON.  Here is one way to do it:

```
public static string Transform(string json)
{
    JObject root = JObject.Parse(json);

    JObject itemsObj = new JObject();

    foreach (JObject item in root["items"])
    {
        JToken id = item["id"];
        id.Parent.Remove();
        itemsObj.Add(id.ToString(), item);
    }

    root["items"].Parent.Remove();
    root.Add("items", itemsObj);

    return root.ToString();
}
```

If you pass your original JSON to this method, you will get the following output:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "A Test",
  "items": {
    "157": {
      "title": "some article",
      "type": "Article"
    },
    "153": {
      "title": "some other article",
      "type": "Article"
    }
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1di41P